# HTML - Create a left menu occupying a part of the main page

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I'm creating a website with ASP.NET MVC 4 with HTML, C#, CSS, Jquery, JQuery Mobile,...

This is my homepage :

[image]

This is my future menu :

[image]

And I would like that when I click on the left-top button on my homepage, the menu slips to the right of the page and so, we'll see just a part of the homepage. For example, 70% of the page is for the menu and the rest for the page. In below, this is an example of result that I want :

[image]

Is the menu a div tag or a view ? How can I do to slip a menu to the right ?

Thank you

Comment: This tutorial should help http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-sliding-menu/

Answer (score 0):

this might help => **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KJz7u/1/)**

```
$('#menu, #content').height($(window).height());
var opened=false;
$('#visit').click(function(){
    if(!opened){
        $('#menu').animate({marginLeft:'0px'},500);
        $('#content').animate({marginLeft:$('#menu').width()+'px'},500);
        opened=true;
    }
    else{
        $('#content').animate({marginLeft:'0px'},500);
        $('#menu').animate({marginLeft:'-'+$('#menu').width()+'px'},500);
        opened=false;
    }
});
```